# Why are the start/stop buttons grey -- cannot start Apache (NOT TOMCAT) within Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, apache

I have an Apache question.  I've searched on here and seen lots of Tomcat questions but the solutions in such threads do not apply.

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen 2017.1a.  I have Apache (non-AMP provided) installed in c:\apache\latest.

In Eclipse, I've done this:

Click Window -> Show View -> Servers
Right click inside servers tab
New - > Server -> HTTP Server -> Next
Hostname: localhost
Add publishing dir: c:\Apache\latest\www
Add port:  8080

In the Servers view the newly created server appears but both the start and stop buttons are greyed out.  I cannot manage the server from Eclipse.  How can I get those start/stop buttons to be active?

Comment: Considering that you didn't have to tell it where the server binary is located, are you sure it starts and stops the HTTP Server instead of just publishing to the document root correctly and opening your files on the server with the right URLs?

Comment: Where is the field to list the path to specify the httpd.exe file?  In the Server Overview tab there are fields for "Server name", "hostname", "Runtime environment" -- which expands to "Name" and "Publishing Directory" (which is already provided in the OP), "URL Prefix" (which isn't needed), and "Port".  In which one of those fields should the binary go? "Name" is just a string. "hostname" isn't the binary, and RT is filled in by Eclipse,

Comment: I'm asking if you're sure that it even does start/stop for that kind of server? What does the server status say in the Servers View?

Comment: Why are you answering my question with a question?  It's NOT helpful discourse in the least.  If you don't know how to manage the server from Eclipse, don't reply.

Comment: As I questioned the first time, **maybe it doesn't actually start and stop and only publishes for this type of server**. Have you seen instructions, a demo, or documentation showing otherwise?

Comment: @MGoBlue93 People are only asking questions because they are trying to help. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @skomisa... it's not that.  It's frustrating when others reply for no other sake than replying. In the OP I documented the click by click steps I took when performing the action. My reply on 22 Feb documented all the fields and their values in the server's properties page. How could I have been any more specific? The resulting question demonstrates zero experience with configuring Apache in Eclipse. That reply does nothing to move the topic along -- it's just there for participation points and thus just waters down the community aspect of the site -- ala what Spiceworks is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nitind pointed out in the comments above, when you create an **HTTP Server** in Eclipse (**New -> Server -> Basic -> HTTP Server**) you are not really creating a server in the conventional sense.

Instead you are creating a mechanism for publishing to some actual server, such as an Apache web server that is running externally to Eclipse, and independently of Eclipse. The sole link between the **HTTP Server** in Eclipse and the actual server is made during the **HTTP Server** creation process when specifying the **Publishing Directory**. For example, if you want to publish to an external Apache server:

[image: setPubDir]

Eclipse will automatically start your **HTTP Server**. Given that it is not really a server in the conventional sense, there is no need to be able to  restart or stop it, so there is no **Start** button and the **Restart** and **Stop** buttons are permanently grayed out.

A few more points:

- The target web server does not need to be running when you publish from your **HTTP Server**. Of course you may still need to (re)start your target web server (externally from Eclipse).
- I do not know of an easy way to instantiate an Apache server within Eclipse, so using an **HTTP Server** is a convenient mechanism for deployment, but the naming choice is not good. I think the situation would have been much clearer if Eclipse's **HTTP Server** had been named (say) **Publishing Server**.
- I couldn't find any Eclipse documentation on the role of an **HTTP Server**.
- If you want to test your static web projects using a server within Eclipse one option is to use an **HTTP Preview** server instead of an **HTTP Server**. An **HTTP Preview** server can be started, stopped and restarted within Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about HTTP Preview server... did not know that. +1